# Convert array to json with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would change the shape of the array into json but difficulty in parsing the data, I have an array like :

```
Array ( [id] => 1
        [fisrt_name] => raul
        [last_name] => gonzales
        [tgl_booking_start] => 2013-11-04 00:00:00 
        [tgl_booking_finish] => 2013-11-30 00:00:00 
      ),
      ( [id] => 2
        [fisrt_name] => chirtiano
        [last_name] => ronaldo
        [tgl_booking_start] => 2013-11-04 00:00:00 
        [tgl_booking_finish] => 2013-11-30 00:00:00 
      )
```

I want to change it into a form json like this, how do I start the code?

```
   [{
   "id":1,
   "title":"raul gonzales",
   "start":"2013-11-04",
   "end":"2013-11-30"
   },
   {
   "id":2,
   "title":"chirtiano ronaldo",
   "start":"2013-11-04",
   "end":"2013-11-30"
  }]
```

thanks for answering

Comment: What's wrong with `json_encode()`? Doesn't it do what you want?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why json_encode http://us1.php.net/json_encode is not suitable?

Comment: You'll need to write your own loop to change the keys and combine first and last name into title, there's nothing built-in to do that.

Comment: I've tried it but I am not parsing the data associated array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sample Link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZoVrOW)

```
 <?php
        $array = array ( 
              array( 'id' => '1',
                'fisrt_name' => 'raul',
                'last_name' => 'gonzales',
                'tgl_booking_start' => '2013-11-04 00:00:00' ,
                'tgl_booking_finish' => '2013-11-30 00:00:00' ,
              ),
              array( 'id' => '2',
                'fisrt_name' => 'chirtiano',
                'last_name' => 'ronaldo',
                'tgl_booking_start' => '2013-11-04 00:00:00', 
                'tgl_booking_finish' => '2013-11-30 00:00:00', 
              ) 
          );

        $new_arr = array();

        foreach($array as $arr){
                $process_array = array();
                $process_array['id'] = $arr['id'];
                $process_array['title'] = $arr['fisrt_name'].' '.$arr['last_name'];
                $process_array['start'] = $arr['tgl_booking_start'];
                $process_array['end'] =  $arr['tgl_booking_finish'];

                array_push($new_arr,$process_array);

         }

         echo json_encode($new_arr);

    ?>
```

output would be

```
[{
"id":"1",
"title":"raul gonzales",
"start":"2013-11-04 00:00:00",
"end":"2013-11-30 00:00:00"
},
{
"id":"2",
"title":"chirtiano ronaldo",
"start":"2013-11-04 00:00:00",
"end":"2013-11-30 00:00:00"
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use json_enconde($array) for convert array to json and  and json_decode($json) for convert json to array.

In javascript access json elements for index example:
 $json['title']

Answer (score 2):

use `json_encode()` See the docu for usage.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function.

```
json_encode($array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want a more powerful solution than the built-in `json_encode` function (mainly for object serialization), try the JmsSerializer library (used a lot in Symfony2 projects) : http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

Answer (score 0):

Consider using both [`stripslashes`](http://www.php.net/stripslashes) and [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) functions to avoid unexpected problems.

```
echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));
```